# Using CSS variables (color) with chart.js - "var(--primaryColor)" not working

Tags: chart.js

I've got a web-app project that uses **two stylesheets** to define **two color sets** (day & night mode). Each stylesheet defines the same CSS variables with different colors (e.g. "*--primaryColor: 'white*'" in *dayMode.css* and "*--primaryColor: 'black'*" in *nightMode.css*. The stylesheet is toggled when clicking a button.

Now, all elements are colored by referring to these variables - both in the CSS and JS code. For example:

```
div {background-color: var(--primaryColor);}

$(this).css({backgroundColor: "var(--primaryColor)"});
```

When switching the stylesheet, **all elements adjust to the new definitions**. Now I set up my very first Chart.js and tried to color it with my variables, like:

```
yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        fontColor: "var(--primaryTextColor)"
    }
}]
```

But that **doesn't work**. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes, see comment below.

Answer (score 34):

CSS variables are used in stylesheet, if you would access them in JS you can do like below snippet:

```js
var style = getComputedStyle(document.body);
var primCol = style.getPropertyValue('--primaryColor');
$("#mydiv").text("primaryColor: " + primCol);
```

```css
:root {
  --primaryColor: #336699;
}

#mydiv {
  background-color: var(--primaryColor);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">

</div>
```

So in a chart.js:

```js
var style = getComputedStyle(document.body);
var primCol = style.getPropertyValue('--primaryColor');
var chartCol = style.getPropertyValue('--chartColor');

var chartData = {
  labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'value',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(219, 20, 0, 0.2)',
    borderColor: chartCol,
    data: [30, 50, 25, 10]
  }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
   legend: { display: false },
    scales: {    
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontColor: primCol,
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --primaryColor: #00ff00;
  --chartColor: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for your answer! Unfortunatly, that doesn't help. Yes, I can access the variables this way, but they won't update automatically when switching the CSS file. Even if I update them manually by gathering the variables in a "update variables function" again and do myChart.update(); , it won't change them.

Comment: The above solution does work, although the issue here is it looks like you are not setting all the needed params for the chart in order to change the font colors: 
You would need also to set the `fontColor` parameter in `chart.config.options.legend.labels.fontColor`, `chart.config.options.scales.[xAxes].scaleLabel.fontColor`, `chart.config.options.scales.ticks.fontColor`, and maybe as well in `chart.config.options.scales.[xAxes].ticks.fontColor`